# An English word describing a pseudo-job

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a job that doesn't actually contribute to increasing productivity in a country and even if you make them disappear, it won't change the way people live or the country's economical prosperity for example being a street vendor, a busker, a clergyman who just preaches and talks around and receives money, fortunetellers, or a person who sells cigars along the street (like a vendor). Usually these jobs are frowned upon by economists.

In my native language there is a word for it that its literal translation is *a pseudo-job*. Is there an English word for this kind of jobs?

**Edit**: To make the meaning clearer I add an example from a context: I saw a local newspaper headline going like this: *"Our skilled labor force now in danger of doing **pseudo-jobs**."* In the article it argues that we cannot provide our skilled experts with job opportunities that they can benefit us most. As a result they start *pseudo-jobs* like being *mourners, vendors, fortune tellers, flyer distributors, etc*.

If you want to write this piece of news in English, how would you go?

Comment: @James Kilfer Actually there is a general debate on whether they're real jobs or not. In sociology, (illegal) vendoring is considered a real job though you can always buy some fruit leather from a supermarket. Perhaps the definitions are alittle tricky based on whether you live in a developed or a developing country but here kids are always advised not to buy anything from vendors. Based on this, fortune telling is probably not a productive job though there's demand for it. The ecpression in my language is exactly what I put there i.e. an _unreal job_.

Comment: As FumbleFingers mentioned "who defines utility" however we have such a general expression to call these jobs and I wondered if there is a similar expression in English too.

Comment: @Yuri I think your question may be as much about culture as about language. At least in the U.S., there is no debate: the examples you cite are all "real" jobs. We don't think of handing out flyers or busking as "pseudo-jobs." Rather we think of them as jobs with, let's say, a very low ceiling for advancement.

Comment: Oh, perhaps, I wasn't aware of that. I thought it might be a common term in human sciences. Anyway, I think this phenomenon still must have a name or a description. In the context that I put up there (the newspaper) you definitely won't describe these jobs as pseudo-jobs but still they're kind of jobs that don't match the workers' skill. Perhaps there is a way to describe that, isn't it? How would you re-write the headline to keep the impact it's trying to make?

Comment: Thank you P. E. Dant your comments were really helpful and informative. They made me aware of the fact that it's a cultural phenomenon.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: AFAIK under-employed means something completely different. It's a word you apply to someone who is employed but whose employment does not match their qualifications/abilities or their own professional/employment goals.

Comment: @R.. Well, that is exactly the situation Yuri describes when he writes: _"...we cannot provide our skilled experts with job opportunities that they can benefit us most. As a result they start pseudo-jobs..."_ If a trained engineer is selling cigars at curbside, surely he is "under-employed" as we use the term!

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Yes, but that contradicts with "doesn't actually contribute to increasing productivity in a country" and the meaning I would gather from "pseudo-job".

Comment: I've heard the term ["bullshit jobs"](http://strikemag.org/bullshit-jobs/) for unnecessary administrative work that could be eliminated without adverse effect. Not sure whether this is understood outside a small circle that cares enough about both economics and sociology to read a multi-page article, though.

Comment: Hi Yuri, would you mind giving the word you use in your native language. It will help other speakers of your own tongue to come up with any good equivalent. It's also interesting for the rest of us to see how languages we don't ken cope with different concepts.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal  sure, it's شغل کاذب /shoghle kazeb/ I suspect the idea behind it comes from communism.

Comment: Not sure if the word in your native language is colloquial (slang) but the expression _oxygen thief_ comes to mind. Possibly a bit harsh. :-)

Comment: News article (in persian) discussing this issue, and giving examples.  The idea of a "mouner" is a new one to me. http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/544040/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%B4%D8%BA%D9%84%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B0%D8%A8

Comment: @penfold actually it's not a slang. It's more of a formal term used by economists, socioligist, and editors. Your word reminds me of a _freeloader_ :) thanks anyway cuz that was new to me.

Comment: @James Kilfiger I saw گریه کن (cryer) in an article and figured maybe the best equivalent for it would be _mourner_. It reminded me of the movie چند میگیری گریه کنی؟ (how much to cry?) :)

Comment: @ritwik sinha That's correct. You should put it there as an answer http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/disguised-unemployment.asp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One problem is that, even if English has a word with the same *meaning*, that word would not indicate the same *group of activities*.   Many native English speakers would not consider *vending* or *busking* to be pseudo-jobs.   Street-vending provides convenience in addition to the offered goods.   Busking allows a performer to practice his or her craft in addition to exhibiting small-scale entertainment.   Even the guy wearing a sandwich board and distributing fliers is participating in the legitimate business of advertising.

Granted, I doubt that most people would say that clergymen benefit the economy.   However, I wouldn't even want to consider discussing in a public forum whether clergymen benefit society -- religion can be a contentious and controversial topic, where I live.

All that being said, there is a word in English that you may want to consider for your purpose.   The last two concrete examples that you've given are *fortune-telling* and *professional mourning*.   I'm not very familiar with professional mourning.   As an American, I find that such a thing doesn't happen in my culture.   However, I am familiar with excessively expensive funerals, with coffins that cost too much and burial plots that cost too much and wakes & memorial services that cost too much.   I'm also somewhat familiar with fortune-telling, card reading and tea leaf reading and palm reading and, of course, those that claim an inexplicable and inexorable psychic connection with the dead.

One word that describes both those activities is "**scam**".   A scam is a way to gain money *without* providing equal value.   Many (but *not all*) scams are illegal.   Even those scams which are legal are never prestigious.   The economy does not benefit from a scam, and society views any scam as distasteful.

A person who gets his or her primary income from a scam is a **scam artist**.

It is entirely possible that, in your culture and your locale, a visible majority of street vendors are scam artists, in sharp contrast with the obvious social and economic value that many street vendors offer in my culture and locale.

If you and I can agree that many fortune-tellers take money without providing value (to either the customer or to society), then there's a good chance that "**scam**" is the word you want.

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know why you need the translation, but I can imagine your telling a foreign friend "hey, around here, street vendors are scam artists" and  (after a couple of follow-up questions) he'd understand you perfectly.

Comment: I don't think scam really works here, as it implies dishonesty or deceit. Some people might think fortune telling telling is a scam, but people who tell people fortunes and people who go to fortune tellers might both be genuinely considering their craft as valuable. If the fortune teller doesn't know anything about his craft yet claims he can tell the fortune, then he's scamming. If he has genuinely spent his life learning about the craft and then providing services to his clients, we cannot really say he is being deceitful. He might be wrong, but he's not cheating.

Comment: Same with professional mourning. Someone pays them to mourn, and they do what they are paid for. They're not really cheating anyone out of money. If I tell you to send me $2000 now and promise to send you $20M later on from an obscure country but then don't deliver on that promise, that's a scam. I don't think the examples here can really be called a scam.

Comment: "religion can be a contentious and controversial topic, where I live." Fortunately the OP is asking about a practice in the middle east, where religion isn't contentious at all (!)

Answer (score 10):

English has two separate concepts for what you have bound together in one:

**sinecure**:  position that requires no work but still pays well

**unproductive labor**: paid labor that does not add to the national product

(But see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productive_and_unproductive_labour#Neoclassical_economics)

Comment: As I see the idea behind this word is probably from Marxism that you properly mentioned. That's why it's sounds wierd in capitalist culture. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

**Busywork**
This typically applies to an individual's activities but can also apply to a group. [Busywork](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busywork) is activity that creates the appearance of being productive, but actually adds no value.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, *pseudo job* is pretty self sufficient.  If I heard it being used, I would have no problem understanding its purpose.

Having scrolled through the current list of answers, though, I thought I'd throw my interpretations into the mix.

### Grunt work

Typically though, *grunt work* is a bit labor intensive.  Usually it's the jobs that others do not want to do e.g mopping the floors, cleaning out the gutters, picking up the trash thrown on the ground by other workers.

### Expendable / Disposable Jobs

When the context involves a human being, typically we say that person is *expendable*.  Just like a paper bag is *disposable*.  For instance, the metal buggies/trollies/carts you find out in the parking lots of the grocery/department stores have to be collected by someone.  Some might call this an *easy job*, but it doesn't mean that it's a satisfying one.

Anyone can do that job, considering they're not physically disabled.  The job is expendable.

Another example might be someone in the 1800s cleaning horse manure out of the streets.

### McJob

To extend on your actual question though, about this sentence being in a newspaper article

> Our skilled labor force [is] now in danger of [taking] pseudo-jobs.

This is the same concept as college graduates having to take **McJobs**, instead of utilizing their education for which they are in debt.  Check out such an article here.

http://articles.latimes.com/2002/may/28/local/me-jobs28

The construction of this word involves the big company / franchise, McDonald's.  The name McDonald's is so widespread that the "Mc" is able to be detached and prepended to about any word and it would demonstrate a "McDonald's experience", which really sucks in my opinion.  The rhetoric in taking the "Mc" and attaching it to the beginning of the word "Job", is insulting of both the job itself and McDonald's.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mcjob

Comment: McJob actually is included in some of the most reputable English dictionaries. Oxford, American Heritage, Collins, Merriam-Webster. McDonalds tried to get it taken out using various means but failed!

Comment: +1 McJob was my first thought; although it's not a perfect match for all of OP's examples, it's at least right for some of them.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect this might be a cultural phenomenon in your country, and there may be no corresponding notion in English. I have some terms that don't quite fit, but may be of use.

There is a word "makeweight", it means a member of a team who is only there to make up the numbers or fill a quota. Eg. "She may be the youngest programmer, but she's no makeweight".

For jobs that are of questionable legality there is the term "the grey economy" "Unemployment is forcing some to enter the grey economy, and drop out of taxation."

A third term is "Underemployed". Note this is not "unemployed". A person is underemployed if the have a job, but the job is below their training or experience: eg an engineer working as a street cleaner.

However the best bet may be just to use "pseudo-job" and explain the meaning at first use. The quote you gave, with examples of jobs would be easy enough to understand.

Comment: + 1 for _the grey economy_. Still I think there is a way to say that e.g. skilled engineers do some jobs that don't match their skills let's say being a street vendor. :) Obviously I gave up on the first notion that I put up there. As you and P. E. Dant mentioned it's probably something cultural.

Comment: Another term is "underemployed" For someone who is working in a low paid job below their training or experience.

Comment: If it's the case I think you should include this in your answer then because it's the closest to what I meant. I didn't know we can call them _unemployed_. It's a good point. So the headline can be translated somehow into "our skilled force are unemployed"

Comment: "Underemployed" not "unemployed"

Comment: Sorry I wanted to edit that but I forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think the class of jobs you've used to explain the term would fall under street [hustling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hustling).

Hustling often means prostitution or selling drugs, but can also be used for "[off-the-books](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-the-books)" jobs that might be frowned upon, like selling [loosies](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loosies) or designer [knockoffs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knockoff), but that aren't considered serious crimes. The difference in meaning would strongly depend on the context. Hustling is doing jobs or selling things for cash from people passing by on the street. The "worker" may not have a permanent spot and may not be doing the same work every day. They do what they need to do to earn some money, and it isn't a visible part of the economy because there is no sales tax or income tax paid on the sales/earnings.

I would call people who perform on the street while asking for money, like musicians with a place to drop some spare change if you like their playing, [buskers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/busker) and not hustlers. People who just ask for money without trying to sell you a service or product are [panhandlers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/panhandler).

I would write something like your example sentence as *"As the economy worsens, skilled workers are having to resort to street hustling to make ends meet."*

Comment: Thanks. _Off-the-books_ jobs also can be considered as pseudo-jobs that I described.

Answer (score 6):

**McJob**

> a low-paying job that requires little skill and provides little opportunity for advancement

This is a term that became popular in the 1990s with Generation X. I personally first came across it in a novel by [Douglas Coupland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Coupland).

At the time several new words became popular using the prefix *Mc-* as a pejorative prefix. Perhaps based on the idea that McDonalds food is not *real* food. Or perhaps rather based just on the low-pay no-skill jobs anyone could get at McDonalds if they weren't qualified for a better job.

Believe it or not it has actually been included in several very reputable dictionaries:

- [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=McJob)
- [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mcjob)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/McJob)
- [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mcjob)

The word even has [its very own Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McJob)

Answer (score 3):

You might consider

> 1. low-skill jobs
> 2. unskilled labor
> 3. low-wage/low-paying jobs

3 usually implies 1 and 2 and vice-versa.

Specifically,

> [Unskilled labor](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/unskilled-labor.asp#ixzz4FGYTyo44) is a segment of the workforce associated with a limited skill set or minimal economic value for the work performed.

Now, it says *associated*, but that does stop anyone with *skills* or *higher education* from doing them. This is typical of recent college graduates who are trying figure out their plans, for example.

Another term you might use is

> [menial](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/menial) work
>   Many chores that get labeled as menial are domestic, but other jobs outside of the home are sometimes also considered menial: stuffing envelopes, data processing, repetitive assembly line work

---

Please note, if the article (or you) intend to speak of [*honest work*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=honest%20work), then I would use the terms above. If you intend to speak of jobs that are not honest, then
you might consider

> [hustle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hustle)
>
> 4. *Slang*
>      a. To obtain something by deceitful or illicit means; practice theft or swindling.
> 5. *Slang*
>      a. To sell or get by questionable or aggressive means
>
> [scam](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scam)
>    To defraud; swindle.

Now, for some of these "borderline" jobs, where it might be technically legal but still deceitful (like fortune-telling), then I would call it  "dishonest" or "deceitful" work. I feel like there is a better word to describe this, but I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. This also fits the context and serves my purpose. As I understand since this word that I asked can be an umbrella word different words can be used to describe it based on the context.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think of our lack of an eloquent translation is a cultural thing.  From my experience, most Americans would probably say "bullshit" jobs for lack of a better term and I think most Engish speakers would probably understand it in the right context.  Obviously this wouldn't work out in the local news paper in which case I think the wording would be "pseudo" jobs or possibly "minimum-wage" jobs.  Again, depending on the context, "leech" or "parasite" might also be used if the phrase is to be used derogatory. Another term which is stretching it, but worth mentioning is "pariah," a sort of outcast or exiled phony.  Most "entrepreneurs" start out with a seemingly pseudo-job.  If they become successful the they earn the badge of being called an entrepreneur.  If they fail then they become masters at...whatever the word is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much knowledge of economics but the term that the questioner wants is

> **Disguised-Unemployment**
>   - [Meaning of the word (I did not find this link, @yuri found it)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/disguised-unemployment.asp)
>
> Speaking informally, it means someone who is employed but not according to his skill level. This happens when there are lot more applicants than jobs. As number of jobs are lot less, the people who did not get the jobs had to do jobs inferior to their skill level.

I am extremely sorry if somebody has already posted this term but a quick `Ctrl + F` does not show desired results.

Comment: Good find, but note that this is a term that doesn't have much currency outside technical economic language, and would need to be explained to a general audience

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but based on the definition provided at the page I think that's probably the closest term describing the phenomenon in my country. Others are welcome to share their ideas here to help me get a good grasp of the term. Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesKilfiger ok i will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the examples you gave fall under the heading of informal economy, where the work isn't tracked or taxed by the government. In the US, however, a lot of those street based jobs are regulated and formalized into the economy, with taxes calculated as individual contractors. This may be a cultural reference that is difficult to translate into a single compound word or phrase.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for may be **gig**, referring to short-term employment specific to a particular set of tasks.  The term used to refer to a short (e.g. couple hours) period of work for a musician or musical group, but it's now broadened considerably.  Being a driver giving someone an Uber ride is the new prototypical example of a specific job one might do in the "**gig economy**" that a lot of newspapers etc. are referring to and covering.

> In the US, the “gig economy” is now so [salient](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/jul/26/will-we-get-by-gig-economy) that the phrase and issues have entered the early exchanges of the presidential race.

The jobs you described are providing value to someone, reflected by the fact that people are paying to have those jobs done, but they don't provide the stability and ongoing labor-payment relationship traditionally associated with employment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you looking for a combining form like *pseudo-job* the meaning is false, pretended, unreal and so on ... describing the behavior also describes the job, I think.

Some fine words (Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition (app edition)),

**slacker**, noun, (informal, disapproving), a person who is lazy and avoids work

**shirk**, verb, to avoid doing sth you should do, especially because you are too lazy. There is no room in our organization for **shirkers**.

**goof-off**, noun, a person who avoids work or responsibility. He is a real **goofy**. *or* He is a real **goofer** at work.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for. Please check out the Edit part I just added. Probably it'll help you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The term **non-job** is used to refer to jobs considered not to be useful. It mostly seems to be associated with alleged wasteful spending in local government and novel job titles.

See [Council cuts: Just what is a 'non-job'?, Tom de Castella, BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-12549785)

Answer (score 1):

The prefix **token** is often used to express something that is unnecessary or included for posterity only without having any necessary function.

> done for the sake of appearances or as a symbolic gesture.

Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/token

So a ***token job*** would be a way to describe a job that has no real purpose or value that exists for some superfluous reason.

I think this is different slightly to the jobs you describe though. I would use token job to describe something that is useless, for example a person employed to stand in an elevator and press the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

English has a few terms for the concept of a "fake job," a position that someone is paid to fill -- without doing any actual work.

1)Sinecure
This synonym for a "cushy position" emphasizes that the job is super-easy, a cinch, one that requires no effort or even much time.

2) Featherbedding

This refers to a practice of labor unions of requiring the hire of more union members than there is work for; to retain excess staff (normally union members) to prevent their unemployment.
https://www.google.com/#q=featherbedding+definition

3) A specialized use of this concept is "ecclesiastical benefice."
Sometimes Church positions were filled by people who could collect money but who did not perform any work. This was a kind of unearned income, but which came to the holder by appointment rather than through investments.
https://www.powerthesaurus.org/ecclesiastical_benefice/define

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the word “sinecure” my friend. I was looking for this word as well. I remember it because I read it in the book, “1984” by George Orwell. I looked it up because I didn’t know it at the time. This is a job given to someone to give them status or financial benefit with little to no actual work. You’re welcome.

Comment: Nobody appoints people to be street vendors, mourners, flyer distributors, buskers, or fortunetellers, so this doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: Thank you Matthew Achin for the effort +1. Although I feel that could be related, as Nathan Tuggy pointed out, it's a different concept. We could talk disapprovingly about those politicians who appoint some family member to a position just to provide them with a job. What I'm referring here is a bit different and that's totally understandable on your part because it's something out of a different culture that you might not be familiar with.